# Seeking suggestions for a book with hard problems about surface and volume integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, problem-solving, book-recommendation, surface-integrals

I am interested about the hard problem of surface and volume integral, so can anyone suggest me a book based on the problem on surface and volume integral (containing a lot of hard problem) for practicing and different types problem solving? The book should be theoretical as well as practical, any kind of help is acceptable.

Comment: Maybe Chapters 4 & 5 in [**Introduction to Calculus and Analysis**, Volume 2](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-8958-3) ([.pdf file from somewhere](https://elearning.raghunathpurcollege.ac.in/files/2619F83415875472690.pdf) and [Spanish translation at Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/introduccionalcalculoyalanalisismatematicovolumen2richardcourantfritzjohn)) by Courant/John. FYI, the *Table of Contents* at the Springer page I cited  is probably not correct, because my 1974 copy has *Functions of a Complex Variable* on pp. 769-820 and *Solutions* on pp. 821-939.

Answer (score 0):

G.M Fiftenholtz " Differential and Integral Calculus " vol 3 says advanced integration methods for intrinsic volumes and areas. That's just for beginning